Is it possible to match a blob source and a m3u8 url?
I use a chrome browser extension to parse a webpage that stream a video from a .m3u8 URL.
Is it possible to use the blob URL from the video element to find the source .m3u8 URL?
Here is an example of the video element
<video class="jw-video jw-reset" tabindex="-1" disableremoteplayback="" 
    src="blob:https://www.example.com/c15f59e0-872f-43c0-9811-ef907362ef2b" 
    webkit-playsinline="" playsinline=""
   id="yui_3_17_2_1_1731598374038_37">
</video>

Here are possible .m3u8 URLs:
"https://souvod.bynetcdn.com/vod/smil:vod/example/PRV2/se8SHJBRO2/App/se8SHJBRO2_10.smil/playlist.m3u8?md5=1eIJ0a3gmKuZsbXj2GIA7g&expires=1731653039"
"https://souvod.bynetcdn.com/vod/smil:vod/example/PRV2/T9fPkHmcGS/App/T9fPkHmcGS_10.smil/chunklist_b400000.m3u8?md5=yoWmdzXdGRVlOvJQjsqVwg&expires=1731653048"
"https://souvod.bynetcdn.com/vod/smil:vod/openu/PRV2/se8SHJBRO2/App/se8SHJBRO2_10.smil/chunklist_b400000.m3u8?md5=vq7cq3DmDwbN2YlwGx0zpA&expires=1731653742"

If the Extension simply checks the src of video tag then it cannot help you (ie: here it will only find Blob urls). If you need the .m3u8 badly just use the Developer Tools in the Chrome/Edge browser. Check the "Network" tab.


Is it possible to use the blob URL from the video element to find the source .m3u8 URL?

Nope.
The M3U8 HLS playlist is loaded by script in this case.  The browser itself doesn't do the loading on its own.
That script initializes a MediaSource (part of the Media Source Extension API, or MSE).  A URL to that MediaSource is created, and it has the blob: prefix, even though no actual Blob object is involved.  The script appends data to the MediaSource.  Again, the browser itself doesn't know or care where the data comes from.  The script is just using the Fetch API to get playlist and the media segments it references.
